# Simple Web App in Google App Script - Button not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm having trouble getting my script to work. The HTML loads ok but the button when clicked doesn't do anything so I think I have a problem with .addEventListener("click",function) but I can't figure out what. I cant see anything in the logger at all.

I've written similar web apps before but can't get to the root of the problem; anybody have any ideas?

```
function doGet(e){

  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Form").evaluate();
}

function userClicked(clientInfo){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Sheet_ID');
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName('Form Inputs');
  
  //Add new row for form submission
  ws.appendRow([clientInfo.clientName, clientInfo.partnerName, clientInfo.account_1, clientInfo.account_2, clientInfo.account_3]);
  
//run newclient function
  newclient(clientInfo.clientName, clientInfo.partnerName, clientInfo.account_1, clientInfo.account_2, clientInfo.account_3);
  
  }

//Function used in HTML file to generate HTML output from "page-js" and "page-css"
function include(filename){return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();}
```

The HTML is as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <?!= include('page-css'); ?> <!-- Custom function created to link css page -->

  </head>
  <body>    
   <div class="container">
   <h4></h4>
    <h5>Partnership Details</h5>
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="input-field col s3">
          <input id="client_name" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="client_name">Client Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s3">
          <input id="partner_name" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="partner_name">Partner Name</label>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW -->

    <h5>Please enter accounts</h5>
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="input-field col s3">
          <input id="Acc1" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="Acc1">Account Name</label>
        </div>
     </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW -->
     
     <div class="row">    
        <div class="input-field col s3">
          <input id="Acc2" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="Acc2">Account Name</label>
        </div>
     </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW -->
     
     <div class="row">    
        <div class="input-field col s3">
          <input id="Acc3" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="Acc3">Account Name</label>
        </div>
     </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW -->
    
     <div class="row">
       <button id="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue" type="submit" name="action"><i class="material-icons left">chevron_right</i>Submit</button>
     </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW -->
    </div> <!-- CLOSE CONTAINER --> 

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script>    
 
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",submitClientInfo);
    
    function submitClientInfo() {         
      
      Logger.log("Someone clicked the button");
      
      var clientInfo = {};
      
      clientInfo.clientName = document.getElementById("client_name").value;
      clientInfo.partnerName = document.getElementById("partner_name").value;
      clientInfo.account_1 = document.getElementById("Acc1").value;
      clientInfo.account_2 = document.getElementById("Acc2").value;
      clientInfo.account_3 = document.getElementById("Acc3").value;

      //Send variables to userClicked function in WebApp page
      google.script.run.userClicked(clientInfo);     
      
      //Clear all input boxes after submit is pressed
      document.getElementById("client_name").value = '';
      document.getElementById("partner_name").value = '';
      document.getElementById("Acc1").value = '';
      document.getElementById("Acc2").value = '';
      document.getElementById("Acc3").value = '';
      }
    
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you seem to have a lot going on for one button... maybe temporarily remove anything unnecessary to isolate the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just to explain a bit more there are five input fields on the web page. Clicking the "submit" button should activate the submitClientInfo function which pulls those five bits of info from the web page and passes them to the userClicked function.
I've tried isolating as suggested but even removing everything and just trying to Log "Someone clicked the button" has shown me nothing.

Answer (score 1):

### `Logger.log` is an Apps Script method that works only from the serverside (code.gs)

- For logs from the clientside (Javascript), use `console.log` instead.
- The console logs from client side won't appear in your Apps Script logs or executions
- You find those logs in the developer console of your browser - see [here](https://javascript.info/devtools) for more information
- It is likely that your button works correctly, but there is some error within your Javascript function
- In this case, you will see the error in the developer console

Comment: Thank you, will use this going forward, very useful

Answer (score -1):

You could try this, straight from [google apps script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script):

```
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
var response = ui.alert('are you there?', ui.ButtonSet.OK);


// Process the user's response.
if (response == ui.ButtonSet.OK) {
  Logger.log('The user clicked "OK."');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, it wasn't working because I'd left a space between the script tag and the start of the javascript code and hadn't noticed. Thanks to all who answered